# ip route and rule on boot

Tags: networking, centos, routing, iproute2

I'm trying to have the following rule and route added automaticaly on boot.
Adding them manually make things work.
I'm running `CentOS`.

```
ip rule add from 10.1.10.10/10 dev my-tun table my-table
ip route add default via 100.1.1.1 dev eth0 table my-table
```

I've added this to `/etc/iproute2/rt_tables`

```
1234    my-table
```

I've added this to `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/rule-my-tun`

```
from 10.1.10.10/10 table my-table
```

I've added this to `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-my-tun`

```
default via 100.1.1.1 dev eth0 table my-table
```

But when reboot the route and rule does not figure in `ip rule list` and `ip route list` - only after I've added them manually again.
The `table` seems to be added correctly.

I have to mention, the `my-tun` is created by an application, so perhaps the interface is simply not existing when I try to add the route and rule - but I have no clue...

Comment: Any help would be appreciated... From what I can read this should be the correct way... But doesn't reflect on reboot.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you don't have your default definition created "permanently" for your "route-eth0" file, which would just be:

```
default via 100.1.1.1 dev eth0 table my-table
```

Here's a CentOS based description of configuring both temporary and permanent routes:
     https://my.esecuredata.com/index.php?/knowledgebase/article/2/add-a-static-route-on-centos

Let me know if this helps!